# DIV moving with computer time on page load

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a project and I was wondering if anyone can assist with this piece of JS code. I am trying to make the DIV move on page load. So, say for example the time is 9am; I want it to move by 100px and 9:30am move by 120px.

Thanks a lot.

```
function slide(element, pixels, duration) {
    var start = new Date();

    var start_x = parseInt(element.style.left, 10);

    function frame() {
        var now = new Date(),
            elap = now - start,
            frac = Math.min(elap / duration, 1),
            pos = start_x + (pixels * frac);

        element.style.left = (pos || 0) + "px";

        if (frac < 1) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);
        }
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}

var div = $('#slideme');
$('#slideme').load('#slideme', function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("slideme");
    slide(elem, -200, 1000);
});
```

Comment: You appear to be using JQuery, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I am using jQuery.

Comment: Ok, and why does 9:00am=100px and 9:30am=120px? What would you want 4am to equal?

Comment: Alright, I am working on an EPG (Electronic Programme Guide). The logic is to move the div according to a user's computer time. If there is a way to make every 30 minutes add 20px to the previous px?

Comment: setInterval(function() { add 20px }, 30 * 60 * 1000);

Answer (score 3):

Have a play with this JQuery:

```
// Current datetime
var d = new Date();

// Total minutes since midnight
var totalMinutes = (d.getHours() * 60) + d.getMinutes();

// Number of 30 minute intervals (since midnight)
var numberOf30Mins = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 30);

// Work out how many pixels that should be (20px per interval)
var numberOfPixelsToShift = numberOf30Mins * 20;

$('#slideme').css('left', numberOfPixelsToShift);
```

Comment: @user2740929 if this worked for you, up-vote and accept it as the answer. :)

Comment: John someone should be up it because I don't have up to 15 reputation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2740929 what has scrolling got to do with this?

Comment: Ask another question for this scrolling issue. and you now have 16 rep. So you can do that. :P

Comment: @gvee when the div moves...is there a way to scroll back to the starting point? If that's the right question to ask. Thanks.

Comment: @user2740929 yeah.. not enough detail mate! Start a new question and provide as much info as you can.

Comment: @gvee the new question is here now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639925/how-to-move-div-back-to-starting-point - thanks.

Comment: @user2740929 quick question... if you remove the code I've given above, does your problem still occur? Wondering if we should be scrolling the window left, rather than setting the CSS left property...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this:

```
$('#slideme').animate({"left": -200}, 1000);
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yzTeJ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use animate function of jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#block" ).animate({
marginLeft: "+1200px",
}, 3000 );
});
```

Comment: Two issues: **1)** `$.ready()` is pretty much useless. If you put your JS code just before `</body>`, then it gets executed as soon as DOM has been complete. **2)** when you animate something, you expect people to see it. the `$.ready()` is executed because user sees the page.